# GAE (python), making data available across requests

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have just started with GAE/python and I am struggling on how to avoid the use of global data for my following needs. (By using this global variable, I am ending up with strange application behavior sometimes)

```
my_data = []

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
my_data = "Set this value"
self.response.write('<form action="/next_page" method="post">')
self.response.write('<input type="submit" value="Next Page"></form>')


class NextPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
# use  my_data variable.


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/', MainPage),
('/next_page', NextPage),
], debug= True)
```

Is memchache the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to share data between two different requests, you'll need some type of persistent storage, Memcache, Datastore, Cloud SQL, or other.